# Elastic Beanstalk CLI Deploy zip error

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, zip, command-line-interface, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

When trying to deploy with awsebcli on osx Yosemite and python 3.4 I get the following output and error:

```
Creating application version archive "app-150701_094953".
ERROR: ValueError :: ZIP does not support timestamps before 1980
```

Seems that there is something wrong with the zip service but I've been looking around and so far I haven't found a working solution.

Edit:

```
Retrieving logs...
(edify)7ddf32e17a6ac5:edify me$ eb deploy --debug 
2015-07-01 14:18:08,842 (DEBUG) eb : logging initialized for 'eb' using    
LoggingLogHandler
2015-07-01 14:18:08,842 (DEBUG) cement.ext.ext_plugin : plugin config  
dir /etc/eb/plugins.d does not exist.
2015-07-01 14:18:08,843 (DEBUG) cement.ext.ext_plugin : plugin config  
dir /Users/me/.eb/plugins.d does not exist.
2015-07-01 14:18:08,844 (DEBUG) eb : collecting arguments/commands for   
<ebcli.core.base.EbBaseController object at 0x10bfdc908>
2015-07-01 14:18:08,848 (DEBUG) eb : collecting arguments/commands for  
<ebcli.controllers.deploy.DeployController object at 0x10bfea3c8>
-- EBCLI Version: 3.4.5
-- Python Version: 3.4.3 (default, Feb 25 2015, 21:28:45) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.56)]
2015-07-01 14:18:08,854 (DEBUG) ebcli.core.fileoperations : Project   
root found at: /Users/me/PycharmProjects/edify
2015-07-01 14:18:08,869 (DEBUG) ebcli.objects.sourcecontrol : Git    
Version: git version 2.1.3.36.g8e36a6d
2015-07-01 14:18:08,878 (DEBUG) ebcli.objects.sourcecontrol : git  
symbolic-ref result: refs/heads/master
2015-07-01 14:18:08,879 (DEBUG) ebcli.core.fileoperations : Project   
root found at: /Users/me/PycharmProjects/edify
2015-07-01 14:18:08,882 (DEBUG) ebcli.core.fileoperations : Project   
root found at: /Users/me/PycharmProjects/edify
2015-07-01 14:18:08,885 (DEBUG) ebcli.core.fileoperations : Project  
root found at: /Users/me/PycharmProjects/edify
2015-07-01 14:18:08,892 (DEBUG) ebcli.objects.sourcecontrol : Git   
Version: git version 2.1.3.36.g8e36a6d
2015-07-01 14:18:08,896 (DEBUG) ebcli.objects.sourcecontrol : git   
symbolic-ref result: refs/heads/master
2015-07-01 14:18:08,897 (DEBUG) ebcli.core.fileoperations : Project   
root found at: /Users/me/PycharmProjects/edify
2015-07-01 14:18:08,900 (DEBUG) ebcli.core.fileoperations : Project   
root found at: /Users/me/PycharmProjects/edify
2015-07-01 14:18:08,902 (DEBUG) ebcli.core.fileoperations : Project    
root found at: /Users/me/PycharmProjects/edify
2015-07-01 14:18:08,905 (DEBUG) ebcli.core.fileoperations : Project   
root found at: /Users/me/PycharmProjects/edify
2015-07-01 14:18:08,907 (DEBUG) ebcli.core.fileoperations : Project 
root found at: /Users/me/PycharmProjects/edify
2015-07-01 14:18:08,914 (DEBUG) ebcli.objects.sourcecontrol : Git   
Version: git version 2.1.3.36.g8e36a6d
2015-07-01 14:18:08,918 (DEBUG) ebcli.objects.sourcecontrol : git    
symbolic-ref result: refs/heads/master
2015-07-01 14:18:08,918 (DEBUG) ebcli.core.fileoperations : Project    
root found at: /Users/me/PycharmProjects/edify
2015-07-01 14:18:08,921 (ERROR) eb : This branch does not have a   
default environment. You must either specify an environment by typing   
"deploy my-env-name" or set a default environment by typing "eb use my- 
env-name".
```

Comment: Hey! Could you add more details like exact CLI command you use, etc.?

Comment: You can run with the --debug option and that will give you a stack trace and (possibly) more information.

Comment: Thanks for the debug flag suggestion, that gave me what I needed to fix the command. So I used `eb deploy ` but didn't have a default profile or region setup so it was failing. The zip error really lost me there. Any ideas of why that came out?

Answer (score 2):

You could run `eb deploy -v` to verify exactly where the error is stemming from. For me, I faced this error while trying to deploy an `express` application to elastic beanstalk. By running the above command I found out that the error was because of a faulty version of `uglify-js` which contained files with timestamps from 1969. Simply downgrading uglify js from `v2.8.28` to `v2.8.27` which did not have the 1969 timestamps fixed the problem for me. You read about this problem [here](https://discuss.circleci.com/t/zip-does-not-support-timestamps-before-1980/13110/3)

Comment: `eb deploy -v` saved the day for me, it zeroed in on the culprit

Answer (score 1):

You probably forgot to commit the project (don't forget that ebcli runs the project based in the git repository!)

Comment: Right, thanks. The issue was actually not having required info on my eb profile. Weird error though.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution [here](https://discuss.circleci.com/t/zip-does-not-support-timestamps-before-1980/13110/10)

add to your package.json scripts:

```
"scripts": {
    "install": "find ./node_modules/* -mtime +10950 -exec touch {} \\;"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use your local files instead by passing the deploy script a `--staged` flag, given you have at least staged your changes.

Answer (score 0):

Often times it's because you are unnecessarily deploying the node_modules folder to elastic beanstalk.  There's a ton of files in there, and one of them is likely the culprit.  But EB will create it's own node_modules folder when it does an `npm install` command...

So if this applies to you, the fix is to add `node_modules` to your .ebignore file.